# Detecting areas of isotropic vs anisotropic diffusion in a flood-fill (or similar) operation

Tags: graph

Hello fellow programmers!

I have a 2D graph which is best described as a Cartesian grid with traversible and non-traversible cells.  I'd like to be able to detect subsets of this graph where the diffusion behaves anisotropically, i.e.: it is constrained by corridor-like passages.

I initially turned to [diffusion tensor imaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_tensor_imaging#Diffusion_tensor_imaging) in neuroscience, but I'm having a great deal of trouble digesting the material.  I'm wondering if any of this has already been distilled into a usable algorithm, or if there are other approaches that could be fruitful.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to determine the following:

1. Areas in which diffusion is *anisotropic*:  highly constrained to two directions (think of water flowing through a 2D slice of a straw).
2. Areas in which diffusion is *isotropic*: largely unconstrained (i.e., water is diffusing through a large, **though irregularly-shaped** space.

Since the graph only contains very narrow or open areas, it would be sufficient to determine **either** anisotropic **or** isotropic diffusion and deduce the other one with a simple contrast.

**TL;DR**:  How can I find the "average" *direction* of a diffusion in a flood-fill or similar operation?

**EDIT:** Here's an example of my graph as an image:

[image]

Comment: Could you post an image example of your grid?

Comment: @leonbloy,  I hesitate because it's unpublished scientific data.  I'll see if I can post a dummy example, or some sort of schematic representation.

Comment: @leonbloy, I've added a representative example.  Does this help?

Comment: If you add n "random walkers" to a n random start nodes, make them move to a random neighboor each time step, count how many times each node are 'touched' by a random walker after (many) iterations, you're probably going to have something close to what you want. I did something like that to find tortuosity of a porous media back in college. Google for 'random walker'

Comment: @VitorBraga, are you suggesting a sort of 2D histogram of walker collisions?  I like that idea.  It seems very expensive and also doesn't give the diffusion *direction*, but the latter isn't really a problem.  I'll have to toy with this.

Comment: @blz Yes, you got the idea. I remember it being slow as hell for many iterations (about 10^7 back when I did it). I was in college then, so I could just submit a job to a HPC cluster instead of running it on my laptop. If you're in a research setting, you probably have access to a similar resource. I'd send you my paper but it's in Portuguese...

Comment: @VitorBraga, I think I'm going to give your approach a shot -- I'm hoping Moore's law will help me out!  The advantage is that my graph has fairly narrow passages, so I think I should get reasonably good results. A few questions:  (1) How do you handle collisions with the environment with the non-traversible nodes? (2) Are there any optimizations or caveats that I should keep in mind?

Comment: @blz At least for my case, a collision meant the walker stayed in place for that iteration, instead of moving, if I recall correctly. I don't think there's any special optmization but be sure to benchmark your random number generator :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any known solutions, but at first thought a simple flood fill that fills based on connectivity might work.

Assumptions:

- Every node's 'openness' will be a function of its connectivity to other nodes. That is, in a bi-directional graph that simulates a square grid, a completely open node will have 8 edges.

Untested, but the following pseudocode might be capable of finding open areas.

```
public class graph
{
    private static List<node> GetArea(node n)
    {
        if (isConnectedEnough(n))
        {
            yield n;
            yield! GetArea(n.neighbours)
        }
    }

    private static bool isConnectedEnough(node n)
    {
        return n.neighbours.Count >= 3;
            /* better: a connectivity threshold function */
    }
}
```

I envisioned calling GetArea sequentially on the list of all nodes in the graph sorted by connectivity until an area of sufficient size was found. Depending on the characteristics of your graph(s) that might not be sufficient, but I was going on the assumption that the graph was structured such that there were numerous areas separated by passageways (ie. rooms connected by hallways).

The connectivity threshold is the key in this situation. Some experimentation would be required here based on the characteristics of your graph(s) because:

- If the average connectivity of the neighbouring nodes is equal to the connectivity of `n` then the area is very possibly consistent in size (ie. not approaching a choke point, also not expanding in size).
- If the average connectivity of the neighbouring nodes is larger than the connectivity of `n` then we may be expanding into an area. Depending on how *you* define an area, that may be fine, (potentially describes a "pinch" in an area). Careful consideration should be considered here because this also describes corners and "corridors" of width 2 nodes/1 edge (min threshold of 3 would permit corners in the area).

That's all I've got for now, but I'll check back in here. This is an interesting problem.

Comment: This sounds like a very interesting approach, and I'll give it due consideration =)  My only concern is in scalability.  My math isn't very well-honed, but it doesn't seem like this is something that can easily be vectorized (or am I wrong)?  My gut feeling is that there's something to be done with diffusion tensor fields, but I'm severely limited by my mathematical skills there as well.  Lots to think about, in any case -- thanks!  EDIT:  another thing here is that I don't see how we could get the diffusion *direction* with this method.  It's not essential, but it would be extremely helpful.